# LocalBroadcastManager not working properly

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I'm having a little problem here, don't know what is wrong. The LocalBroadcastManager was working as it should be, but after I added some code inside it ( to be able to handle 2 diferent broadcast ) it stoped working don't know why.

Here is the one that was working properly

```
private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        String testeBroadcast = intent.getAction();
        if (testeBroadcast.equals("Loadscreen"))
        {
            alertLoad.cancel();
        }
        fill_Main_TextV();
    }
};
```

It was being sended from here

```
MainActivity testeActivity = new MainActivity();
public static final String intService = "Loadscreen";
public Loadscreen()
{
    super(intService);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    testeActivity.fill_tabcli();
    Intent in = new Intent(intService);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(in);
}
```

The change on the BroadcastReceiver that I did make is :

```
private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        String testeBroadcast = intent.getAction();
        if (testeBroadcast.equals("Loadscreen"))
        {
            alertLoad.cancel();
        }
        if (testeBroadcast.equals("Accoes"));
        {
            CliInfo cliente = GlobalVars.getClientes_Info().get(GlobalVars.get_selected_client()+"");
            for (String idAccoes : nomeficheiros)
            {
                for(accoes_cli teste : cliente.getAccoes())
                {
                    int cliIdAccoes = teste.getId_accao();
                    if (idAccoes.equals(cliIdAccoes+""))
                    {
                        cliente.getAccoes().remove(teste);
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
        fill_Main_TextV();
    }
};
```

And the second sendBroadcast is:

```
public void escreve()
{
    String esc_data = GlobalVars.year+"-"+GlobalVars.month+"-"+GlobalVars.day;
    esc_data=GlobalFunctions.converte_data(esc_data);
    try
    {
        writer = new FileWriter(GlobalVars.folder + "/" + esc_id + "_" + esc_data + ".acc");
        writer.write(esc_accao + ";" + esc_resultado + ";" + esc_c1 + ";" + esc_c2 + ";" + esc_c3);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {   
        e.printStackTrace();
        GlobalFunctions.toast_message(contexto, contexto.getString(R.string.accoes_salvo_erro));
    }
    finally
    {
        GlobalFunctions.toast_message(contexto, contexto.getString(R.string.accoes_salvo));
        MainActivity.nomeficheiros.add(esc_id);
        Intent in = new Intent(intService);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(in);
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Does the BoreadcastReceiver only can handle 1 ( in total ) ?